# How to set environment variables in AWS lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to set environment variables in AWS lambda using python

initially I have an environment variable stackname with no value in lambda configuration.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if os.environ["stackname"]:
        print("Not empty")
        print(os.environ["stackname"])
    else:
        print("its empty")
        os.environ["stackname"]="mystack"
        print(os.environ["stackname"])
```

Now I'm seeing weird intermittent behaviour here for the first I expect to print

```
its empty
mystack
```

and from thereon whenever I execute lambda it should print

```
Not empty
mystack
```

for initial couple of times it prints

```
Not empty
mystack
```

but after couple or more executions lambda prints below which is weird.

```
  its empty
    mystack
```

Please suggest if this is any other better way to set environment variables which gives consistent output.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `stateful` and `stateless`?

Comment: @GuyT Kindly answer, if you understand the question. Do not lay another question to make it useless to the poster and the community.

Answer (score 9):

AWS Lambda functions run inside of an Amazon Linux environment. Sequential invocations of the same Lambda function may result in the function running on the same environment or a different environment. By environment I mean computer, container, etc.

This means that you cannot reliably set environment variables and expect them to be there on the next invocation.

A better approach is to store your run-time variables in persistent storage such as DynamoDB.

Comment: Right, @JohnHanley.  You can use environment variables (or any other persistent storage) to cache "expensive" information, that the first run in a container can get and the remaining runs in that container can use.  But you can't expect the information to be there for any subsequent run of your function, which could be in a different container or even on a different EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as you do in system using os

```
 import os
 os.environ['varible']='value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [environment variable support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html) provided by lambda? You can config the env vars when you create or update your function, and then reference those vars in your function code. Regarding why it prints out 'its empty', @John Hanley's answer is pretty accurate.